# SSRS: How to count true rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

I have a report with a dataset that has a column with booleans. In the table footer I want to display `x / y` where `x` is how many rows that were `true` and `y` is how many rows there was total.

Currently I have this:

```
=Count(Fields!Transfered.Value).ToString() + " / " + CountRows().ToString()
```

But the first becomes same as the last part. I then tried this:

```
=Sum(Fields!Transfered.Value).ToString() + " / " + CountRows().ToString()
```

But that generates an error, which I guess I can understand. I thought that if I converted the booleans into numbers where true is 1 and false is 0, then it could work out nicely. But how can I do that? Or is it a smarter way to do this all together?

**Update:** Have now also tried

```
=Sum(CInt(Fields!Transfered.Value)).ToString() + " / " + CountRows().ToString()
```

And got a negative result... O.o

Also found a way that worked, which I posted as an answer. But I won't accept it as an answer yet incase someone has a better way to do this =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can tell you why things went wrong...

- Count(Fields!Transfered.Value) is simply the number of rows. aka CountRows()
- Sum(Fields!Transfered.Value) is trying to aggregate "true" or "false" = error
- Sum(CInt(Fields!Transfered.Value)) will sum -1 and 0 because VB.NET true = -1
- Sum(IIF(Fields!Transfered.Value, 1, 0)) fixes the sign issue = your solution

To avoid the extra IIF, you could use negate the sum of all the -1s

```
= -Sum(CInt(Fields!Transfered.Value)).ToString() + " / " + CountRows().ToString()
```

In the end, either solution would be OK and both are equally kludgy

Comment: Thanks! Things are clearer now :D (Why would anyone decide to make true = -1??)

Comment: Dunno. To make people hate VB.Net? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to do it, although there is probably a better more clear and logical way...

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Transfered.Value, 1, 0)).ToString() + " / " + CountRows().ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today and at least verified that I wasn't the only one that got a negative sum value for bools out of SSRS.  Thanks.

My solution was to use ABS for absolute value.  I like that better than just negating the expression solely because it's easier to see visually where the '-' might be missed if you're not careful in reading the expression.

but it's essentially the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way where you count on a grouped value

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!TrueOrFalseField.Value, 
                   Fields!GroupedField.Value,
                   "BadValueToBeRemovedFromCount"))
              -IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!TrueOrFalseField.Value)=1 
                                 and First(Fields!TrueOrFalseField.Value)
                    , 0, 1)
```

The second part

```
-IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!TrueOrFalseField.Value)=1 
                                     and First(Fields!TrueOrFalseField.Value)
                        , 0, 1)
```

remove 1 from the count if it has `True` and `False` value or if there are only one distinct `false` value.